# Convert Files From Jpeg

Tags: photo-editing

I use Gimp to edit photos and then I convert the image to Jpeg but it saves as PNG. How do I convert that to Jpeg?

Comment: Try using the web tool over at https://www.browserling.com/tools/png-to-jpg. I don't use gimp, so I'm sorry I can't provide a more technical answer, but this should work fine.

Comment: If you want to save as jpeg grom GIMP, use File > Export.

Answer (score 3):

In gimp you have an option "Export as" and you can choose the format. Then you have to write the extension yourself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want an option "Save as JPG" in gimp file menu you can download some scripts [here](http://www.gimphelp.org/script210.html) with instructions. The pack includes save as jpg script also in along with many others.